# Laravel not receiving post parameters from an Android App

Tags: php, android, json, laravel, api

am facing trouble in reading data posted from android app to laravel method.

My android code for post

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(Constants.SAVE_DETAILS_END_POINT);
try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", name1));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name2", name2));
        ....
        ..
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     }
catch(...
```

And my Laravel code,

```
public function saveDetails(Request $request){
    $modlee = new ModelName();
    $modlee->name1  = $request->get('name1');
    $modlee->name2  = $request->get('name2');;
    ...
    $modlee->save();
    return $modlee;
}
```

I tried to `var_dump($request->get('name1'));` its null

Am always getting the error cannot insert null values, MySQL integrity constraint violation error,

Comment: i think you don`t send name1 param

Comment: @J.Doe I have set it, this line sets the name param `nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name1", name1));`

Comment: em, try to add to your model `protected $fillable = ['name1', 'name2']`

Comment: I dont think that is a problem as it worked fine locally, only when moved to server am facing this issue

Comment: in your controller method try `dd($_POST)`

Comment: dd returns nothing, 
actually i made the post as Route::any as Route::post gives me error saying MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Comment: android send via post or get?

Comment: its post itself.

Comment: i think problem in client